# Athena/Presto : Unnest 2 arrays with left join

Tags: sql, left-join, presto, amazon-athena, unnest

So I have 2 Json arrays that need unnesting, and joining based on a key within the json structure.
In theory is easy, but without having a 'left join unnest' functionality, it all becomes messy.

I have achieved what I want, by grouping the results; but I also have concerns that it is doing 2 cross joins, effectively generating many thousands of superfluous rows (in a live environment) before filtering them back out again.

Hence, my question here, is really looking for a much more efficient strategy to do the same logic. I'm well aware that my Presto experience & knowledge is n its infancy !

Thanks for any guidance !

**Workings:**

**Basic logic :**
Each item in the 'left' array has an $.id value.
For *some* of the 'left' items, there will be a matching right item with $.a.id value

**Examples :**

1. The first SQL & results below show the setup, if not the desired result.
2. The second set, shows my current solution.

(1) Raw results of Cross Join

```
with cte as (
    Select 
        123 as record_id,
        '[ {"id":"01","key1":["val1"]}, {"id":"02","key1":["val2"]}, {"id":"03","key1":["val3"]} ]' as "left",
        '[ {"a":{"id":"02","key1":["apples"]}, "b":{"lala":"bananas"}},{"a":{"id":"01","key1":["one"]}, "b":{"lala":"oneone"}} ]' as "right"
)
select 
    record_id,
    l.i as "left",
    r.i as "right",
    json_extract(l.i, '$.id') as left_id,
    json_extract(r.i, '$.a.id') as right_id
from 
    cte,
    unnest(cast (json_parse("left") as array(json))) as l(i),    -- left array
    unnest(cast (json_parse("right") as array(json))) as r(i)    -- right array
```

Output:

| record_id | left | right | left_id | right_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | {"id":"01","key1":["val1"]} | {"a":{"id":"02","key1":["apples"]},"b":{"lala":"bananas"}} | "01" | "02" |
| 123 | {"id":"01","key1":["val1"]} | {"a":{"id":"01","key1":["one"]},"b":{"lala":"oneone"}} | "01" | "01" |
| 123 | {"id":"02","key1":["val2"]} | {"a":{"id":"02","key1":["apples"]},"b":{"lala":"bananas"}} | "02" | "02" |
| 123 | {"id":"02","key1":["val2"]} | {"a":{"id":"01","key1":["one"]},"b":{"lala":"oneone"}} | "02" | "01" |
| 123 | {"id":"03","key1":["val3"]} | {"a":{"id":"02","key1":["apples"]},"b":{"lala":"bananas"}} | "03" | "02" |
| 123 | {"id":"03","key1":["val3"]} | {"a":{"id":"01","key1":["one"]},"b":{"lala":"oneone"}} | "03" | "01" |

(2) Current Solution

```
select 
  record_id,
  l.i as "left",
  max( if(json_extract(l.i, '$.id') = json_extract(r.i, '$.a.id'),json_format(r.i),null) )as match
from 
  cte,
   unnest(cast (json_parse("left") as array(json))) as l(i),    -- left array
   unnest(cast (json_parse("right") as array(json))) as r(i)    -- right array
group by 
  record_id,
  l.i
```

| record_id | left | match |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | {"id":"01","key1":["val1"]} | {"a":{"id":"01","key1":["one"]},"b":{"lala":"oneone"}} |
| 123 | {"id":"02","key1":["val2"]} | {"a":{"id":"02","key1":["apples"]},"b":{"lala":"bananas"}} |
| 123 | {"id":"03","key1":["val3"]} |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unnest both arrays in CTEs and left join CTEs, in this case you will eliminate cross join, but the code is a bit longer:

```
with cte as (
    Select 
        123 as record_id,
        '[ {"id":"01","key1":["val1"]}, {"id":"02","key1":["val2"]}, {"id":"03","key1":["val3"]} ]' as "left",
        '[ {"a":{"id":"02","key1":["apples"]}, "b":{"lala":"bananas"}},{"a":{"id":"01","key1":["one"]}, "b":{"lala":"oneone"}} ]' as "right"
), 

"left" as (
select 
    record_id,
    l.i as "left",
    json_extract(l.i, '$.id') as left_id
from 
    cte,
    unnest(cast (json_parse("left") as array(json))) as l(i)    -- left array
), 

"right" as (
  select 
    record_id,
    r.i as "right",
    json_extract(r.i, '$.a.id') as right_id
from 
    cte,
    unnest(cast (json_parse("right") as array(json))) as r(i)    -- right array
)

select 
    l.record_id,
    l."left",
    r."right",
    l.left_id,
    r.right_id
from 
    "left" l left join "right" r on l.record_id=r.record_id and l.left_id=r.right_id
```

Result:

| record_id | left | right | left_id | right_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | {"id":"01","key1":["val1"]} | {"a":{"id":"01","key1":["one"]},"b":{"lala":"oneone"}} | "01" | "01" |
| 123 | {"id":"02","key1":["val2"]} | {"a":{"id":"02","key1":["apples"]},"b":{"lala":"bananas"}} | "02" | "02" |
| 123 | {"id":"03","key1":["val3"]} | \N | "03" | \N |